# Python - Find characters in list of strings that are not duplicates

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

I'm having difficulty with finding a non-duplicate value in a dictionary.

```
my_dict = {(1, 1):'2345', (1, 2):'234', (1, 3):'5678', (1, 4):'2387'}
```

What I need is to be able to find out is, what character is not a duplicate and what key it is a value of.
For this dictionary I would need to return the following:

```
>>> {(1, 3):'6'}
```

6 is the only value that does not appear in any of the other values, so I would need to be returned the key ((1, 3)) and the non-duplicate (6).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you say 6 is the only value that doesn't appear elsewhere?  What about 1?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistype, 1 is not supposed to appear in (1, 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_dict = {(1, 1):'2345', (1, 2):'234', (1, 3):'5678', (1, 4):'2387'}

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    for char in v:
        d[char].append(k)
print {v[0]:k for k, v in d.items() if len(v) == 1}
```

If you want to do it only with dictionaries

```
d = {}
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    for char in v:
        d.setdefault(char, []).append(k)
print {v[0]:k for k, v in d.items() if len(v) == 1}
```

**Output**

```
{(1, 3): '6'}
```